# Autoplay embedded a YouTube Video

Tags: html, youtube

I'm trying to embed a Youtube video to my site that plays automatically once the page is loaded.

I'm currently using:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/V4kXFYRhwL0" 
        frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

However the video doesn't play until clicked. What is wrong with this code?

Link to site: http://oxfordcliqr.com/

Answer (score 11):

Add this into the URL string:
?autoplay=1&mute=1

This will set the property autoplay to 1 and mute to 1, so the video starts playing once the page is loaded.

Due to the policy changes, autoplay videos only works if the video is muted.

Example:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/V4kXFYRhwL0?autoplay=1&mute=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: I've updated the code, but the video is still paused until the play button is clicked

Comment: @Marcus the autoplay function like I mentioned before is not working since April 2018, google made some changes.

Comment: Actually `&autoplay=1` can work even *without* mute, however, Media Autoplay *must* be enabled on the *browser*. For example, in Edge, it can be enabled by going to *Settings > Cookies and Site Permissions > Media autoplay*. I have not found a way around this, even with the YouTube JS API. Due to browser restrictions, media is not allowed to autoplay with sound without being explicitly enabled by the user.

Answer (score 1):

pass `autoplay=1` to auto play in youtube URL and `mute=1` to mute it, both works when page get load completely

eg: `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/V4kXFYRhwL0?autoplay=1" ></iframe>`

Comment: I've updated the code, but the video is still paused until the play button is clicked

Comment: @Marcus try the mentioned example

Comment: here is the working [example](https://jsbin.com/temeruzowi/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Still paused, even in your working example... I'm using Chrome 85.0.4183.102 maybe this is an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use below iframe URL to the autoplay youtube video

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Zm4zpyn0ixw?autoplay=1&mute=1"></iframe>
```